# Get worker id in a apache beam job

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, apache-beam-io

Is it possible to get the worker-id from a apache beam job? Or any unique identifier that can tell about the current worker ? Cause I want to use it as label for my metric.

Thank you.

Comment: Worker - you mean individual machines spawned?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this is supported but feel free to file a [JIRA](https://beam.apache.org/community/contact-us/) for this and mention your use-case. Also note that such information might be runner specific so you might be able to get information regarding the workers started for a job through the API of the runner you are using.